# some problem to display the content of a page in another page in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, function

for a wordpress project i have some problem to display the content of a page, in home page ...
i want only display frist 20 characters in the page ...
i use this :

```
        <?php

        $post   = get_post( 90 );
        $output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
        $output=substr($output,0,20);
        echo $output;


        ?>
```

it's show something but Comes with a number of errors, for example not correclty 20 characters and some times show undefined characters ...

can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have content in utf-8 try `mb_substr` instead `substr` and if content is html, use `strip_tags`

try sth like this

```php
<?php
        $post   = get_post( 90 );
        $output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
        $output=mb_substr(strip_tags($output),0,20);
        echo $output;
```

for exact count chars

```
<?php
        $post   = get_post( 90 );
        $output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
        if (preg_match('#^.{1,20}#s', strip_tags($output), $matches)) {
                $output = $matches[0];
        }
        echo $output;
```

Comment: im try your code , for example when i change the lentgh from 20 to 2 then nothing disapear ... , and when the lentgh is 20 only echo 17 characters ... this make me confused

Comment: if you need exact count charactes from start string, try this `if (preg_match('#^.{1,20}#s', strip_tags($output), $matches)) {  $output = $matches[0]; }`

Comment: This conversation took a little longer ... i'm sorry for that 
but i'm also try that but that echo only nine characters ...

Comment: if the chars will not work correctly, then is there a way to limit the words instead of the charaters ?